# I keep encountering error in trying to access the most common functions through a JS module file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am starting fresh on my learning JS journey. So as basic practice of using modules to callback certain functions I have done the following.

This is my HTML file, with the following code.

```
<title>
    Basic Login
</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="User" placeholder="UserName">
    <input type="password" name="Pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <script src="JS_1.js">    </script>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    <p id="lumberjack"></p>
</body>
```

[The actual output of the HTML code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Wxx.png)

With this in place as foundation, I have created two JS files. They are JS-1.js and Test.js

JS-1.js will act as the main JS file with the following code.

```
import alt from 'test.js';
document.getElementById("lumberjack").innerHTML = "This prints";
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click',alt);
```

Test.js will act as the function JS which will export the common module. Currently it has just the following code:

```
export function alt(){
    alert("Check the console");
    console.log("Ok, this works too you");
}
```

However, I keep encountering errors.
[The error seen in the console of the HTML file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESVpk.png)

From what I have learnt, since I am using a local HTML, ES is not able to parse the JS file properly for usage because it is not through HTTP. From scouring the internet I have tried multiple things like installing live-server through npm (I tried to start it but it says file not found), I tried using
`const alt = require('test.js')`, I tried changing the extension of the function JS file to test.mjs from test.js but none of these seem to have worked. I don't get what I should do here.

Comment: Your script should have type `module` because you are using `import`: `<script type="module" src=""/>`. The error you see is because you use a `file:` url to load assets, but you should use `localhost:`. You can enable localhost in lots of ways, an easy way to do it is the `live server` extension for VS Code